# Python C API: Using the property decorator from a C extension

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm writing a python module in C that provides a class, wrapping a C API. The C API has some basic accessor methods that I'd like to present as a property in the python class. For example, say I have:

```
int libspam_get_eggs(spam_t *spam, int *eggs);
int libspam_set_eggs(spam_t *spam, int eggs);
```

I know how to create a class CSpam and add get_eggs() and set_eggs() methods to it, but I'd like to present eggs as a property instead. To solve this problem, I could put a python wrapper around the object that does:

```
class Spam(CSpam):
    eggs = property(CSpam.get_eggs, CSpam.set_eggs)
```

But I'd like to do everything in the C API if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`PyTypeObject.tp_getset`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getset) and the `PyGetSetDef` struct.

The signature of the getter and setter functions should match

```
PyObject *libspam_get_eggs(PyObject *self, void *closure);
int libspam_set_eggs(PyObject *self, PyObject *value, void *closure);
```

where `closure` is a `void*` set on the `PyGetSetDef`.